# lost all photo in mobile in samsung galaxy core 2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have a phone name Samsung galaxy core2, my problem is my all photo is save in SD card but it is not showing in the gallery I have even try to remove the SD 
card n restart it but then also it is not showing any photo n then I again insert SD card n restart it this process I have done near by 5 time but then also photo is not showing in gallery, please try to help in collecting my all important photos.

Thank you 
angle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your pictures in file manager. If they are deleted from there too than there is a app which can recover deleted pics or you can recover your pics through computer. Here are both methods.

**Through App**

- Root your Device
- Download these app  "[Undelete recover files and data](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.undelete&hl=en)"
- Allow root access and recover your photos.

**Through PC**

- Download Recuva
- Use a memory card reader or connect your Smartphone to PC
- Open Recuva and choose your SD card
- It will show you all things which can be recoverd.